# Multiple Tailwind CSS classes having multiple Webpack entry points

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css

**Problem statement**

So I have a React project setup with webpack and tailwind CSS.
In my webpack config I have multiple entry point in order to generate different CSS and JS for each entry point.
The problem arises when I use the tailwind classes in my React components.
Let's suppose if I use a tailwind class **bg-red-600** only in Component1(or entry point 1). 
So after building the files through webpack the **bg-red-600** will be present in all the entry point's generated CSS files(keep in mind I have just used this class in first entry point component only).
What it should be doing is only have **bg-red-600** class in first component CSS file instead it is preset in all the CSS files even though I have not used it in any other place other than first component.

Hope I was able to made my point.

Thanks.

Webpack's entry points:

```
entry: {
    app1: path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        'src/Component1'
    ),
    app2: path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        'src/Component2'
    ),

},
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split generated CSS code form Tailwind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56714850/how-to-split-generated-css-code-form-tailwind)

Comment: Hi @TheFool thanks for the reply, but the question is not 100% same.

Comment: what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

1. `/config` folder with custom tailwind-xxx.config file for each entry js

eg. `/config/tailwind-ConfirmButton.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/common/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.jsx',
  ],
  // plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms')],
}
```

2. webpack.config.js

```
const postcssOpts = { postcssOptions: env => {
    // here is the point
    const component = env._module.context.slice(env._module.context.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)

    return { 
      plugins: [
        ['tailwindcss', {
          config: `./config/tailwind-${component}.config.js`,
        }],
        autoprefixer
      ] 
    }
  } 
}

...

entry: {
  confirm: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/widgets/confirmButton.js'),
},
target: ['web', 'es5'], // <=== can be omitted as default is 'web'
output: {
  filename: '[name]/tag.js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/exp'),
  publicPath: './',
},

...

{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    { loader: 'style-loader' },
    { loader: 'css-loader' },
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: postcssOpts,
    },
  ],
},
```

3. entry widget js
   eg. `/src/widgets/customButton.js`:

```
...

render(
  <ConfirmButton
    expId={expId}
    content={content}
    confirmBtn={confirmBtn}
    cancelBtn={cancelBtn}
    field={field}
  />,
  container
)
```

4. finally run `weppack --mode=production`